# Problema con foreach

Tags: php, mysql, sql, condiciones, foreach

Estoy realizando un reporte donde imprimo los medicamentos suministrados a pacientes por cierto periodo de tiempo, queda así.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero que si hay fechas iguales sume las dosis, el monto, concatene el precio unitario y las facturas quedando así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código es este

```js
    $suma=0; 
    $totales=0;
    $i = 9;
    $fecha1="";
    $precio = 0;
  foreach($reporte as $row):
    if ($fecha1 != $row['fecha'] ) {
    $precio = $row['Totalprecio'];
    $dosis = $row['dosis'];
    $factura=$row['noFactura'];
  }else {
    $precio = $precio + $row['Totalprecio'];
    $dosis = $dosis + $row['dosis'];
    $factura=$row['noFactura'].','.$factura;
  }
    $totales = $precio;
    $suma=$suma + $precio;
    
      if ($fecha1 != $row['fecha'] ) {
        $precio = $row['Totalprecio'];
        $dosis = $row['dosis'];
        
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.$i, $row['fecha']);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B'.$i, round($row['peso'],2)." KG");
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C'.$i, $row['Medicamento']);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D'.$i, $dosis);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('E'.$i, $row['precio']);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('F'.$i, 'Monto: $'.round($totales,2). ' 
}

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A'.$i)->applyFromArray($bordear)->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B'.$i)->applyFromArray($bordear)->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('C'.$i)->applyFromArray($bordear)->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('D'.$i)->applyFromArray($bordear)->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('E'.$i)->applyFromArray($bordear)->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('F'.$i)->applyFromArray($bordear)->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
   

    $i++;
  endforeach;
```

Esta es la consulta SQL

```
SELECT a.fecha, a.peso, SUM(d.dosis) AS dosis, a.nDosis,group_concat(f.noFactura,' (',d.dosis,') ') AS noFactura, f.precio * d.dosis AS Tprecio, f.precio, a.Medico, m.nombreMedicamento
             FROM app a
             JOIN dosis d ON a.idDosis = d.idDosis
             JOIN facturas f ON d.idFactura = f.idFactura
             JOIN medicamentos m ON m.idMedicamento = f.idMedicamento
             WHERE a.fecha BETWEEN '2019-02-01' AND '2019-02-31' AND a.idPaciente = '23' GROUP BY  f.noFactura, a.fecha ORDER BY a.fecha;
```

Estoy hecha un lio con esto de los if ya lo intente de varias formas pero no logro que quede como quiero, espero alguien me pueda ayudar de antemano Gracias!

Comment: Podrías hacer una subconsulta de `noFactura` con `GROUP BY` y luego en la consulta general hacer un `GROUP BY` de fecha

Comment: Muchas fracias hice una modificación a la consulta por que faltaba agregar algunos datos.

Comment: El problema que tengo con el GROUP BY es que muestra en Tprecio el valor de Tprecio  de la última factura cuando quiero sumarlos

Answer (score 1):

SQL es muy bueno para hacer sumas, ordenamientos y agrupaciones, por lo que debería ser tu primer opción para ese tipo de tareas. Corrigiendo el agrupamiento te ahorras las sumatorias en PHP, exceptuando Monto Total.

```
SELECT fecha
     , peso
     , medicamento
     , sum(dosis)
     , group_concat(noFactura,' (',dosis,') ') AS noFactura
     , group_concat(precio) AS precio
     , sum(precio * dosis) AS Totalprecio
  FROM aplicaciones  
  WHERE fecha BETWEEN '2019-10-01' AND '2019-10-31' 
    AND idPaciente = '2' 
  GROUP BY  fecha, idMedicamento
```

Comment: Muchas gracias hice una modificacion a la consulta agregando JOIN, me puedes ayudar con el ejemplo.

Comment: Si la relacion es 1:1 no tendrás problema, si es 1:* para cada columna del JOIN que necesites en el SELECT deberás usar alguna función de agregación.